# When should a memo field be used as opposed to a text field in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, database-design

At what point should one consider using the memo field type as opposed to the text field type in a MS Access database? I realize the primary consideration is the length of the field, as text is limited to 255 chars, and the memo field really can't be used in a query criteria, but are there other considerations? The text field reserves the space for every record, but the memo field only uses space for the text entered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned text length as the primary consideration.  For me, that is more like the *only* consideration.  If the field has to hold no more than 255 characters, it will be text instead of memo type.

The only exception I can remember was bumping up against the per-record 4,000 character limit.  See [Access 2010 specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854):

> Number of characters in a record (excluding Memo and OLE Object
>   fields) when the UnicodeCompression property of the fields is set to
>   Yes
>
> 4,000

Since memo fields do not count against that limit, I made some fields memo simply to keep the remainder of the record's character count within the limit.

But that was a one-time situation.

If you want to store Access' "rich text", you would want a memo field.  (Thanks, [Gord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397616/when-should-a-memo-field-be-used-as-opposed-to-a-text-field-in-ms-access/37398333?noredirect=1#comment62305583_37398333).)

Off the top of my head, I can't think of any other reasons to choose memo when text would suffice.

Comment: What about "Rich Text"? (I can't  remember if Access is able do anything terribly useful with Text fields containing HTML markup.)

Comment: The only other possible reason could be file size concerns, although it likely isn't as significant a concern as it once was.

Comment: Not sure what you meant about file size, Blair.  A plain text field does not reserve space to accommodate unstored characters.

Comment: Hmmm, I always thought that a 255 char text field took up 255 (actually 510, due to Unicode text) bytes regardless of content. Thanks for re-educating me.